# Error during trigger execution ORA-06512 And ORA-04088

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have created a trigger so that the user can not enter a CRIME_NO if it doesn't exist in the CRIME table. which does work i do receive the 'Crime Number: '|| :new.CRIME_NO || ' not in the Crime table') error.

However i also receive ORA-06512: at "C3405016.EVIDENCE_FK", line 8 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'C3405016.EVIDENCE_FK'

```
Create or replace trigger Evidence_fk
before insert or update of CRIME_NO
on Evidence
for each row
declare
         dummy   integer;
begin
         select count(*)    into dummy
         from Evidence
         where CRIME_NO = :new.CRIME_NO;
     if (dummy < 1) /* i.e. no corresponding Crime_No in Crime */
             then raise_application_error(-20002,
             'Crime Number: '|| :new.CRIME_NO || ' not in the Crime table');
         end if;
end;
```

ORA-20002: Crime Number: 20 not in the Crime table ORA-06512: at "C3405016.EVIDENCE_FK", line 8 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'C3405016.EVIDENCE_FK'

Comment: That is doing what it should - you get the whole exception stack. But why are you doing this with a trigger at all, rather than with an actual foreign key constraint?

Comment: I'm a student and as part of my coursework i have to implement 2 triggers, i know i could use a constraint but i can also use a trigger and get marks for it.